# OpenNETCF DirectShowPlayerControl display is going black randomly when playing videos if the player is disposed and recreated

Tags: compact-framework, opennetcf

I have a application that runs on touch enabled device with WinCE 3.5 OS. I have a show player control to display adds when the system is left idle for some configured amount of time..

So the DirectShowPlayerControl will be iniated every time the show player is launched and will be destroyed when it is closed...

The player for the first time plays videos continuously for any amount of time. Once the player is destroyed and recreated the video are changing but the display goes black and in between if some small video is placed that alone is displayed.

Whenever the form is closed am calling DirectShowPlayerControl.Dispose() method.

Comment: Can you put together a small sample application that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Have you contacted the OEM's support (i.e. me)?